# SPI communication between FPGA(ZC-706) and Amega128

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, c, embedded

I'm trying to write a communication protocol between an FPGA and a Microcontroller through an SPI, the µC being the Master here.

**FPGA:** ZC-706 (Zynq-7000)
**µC:** ATmega128

Here is the code which i used for the FPGA part. https://github.com/souktha/zybo_spi_slave/blob/master/spi_slave.v

Here's how the code is supposed to look like (as explained in the link above):
. Four wires: MOSI (input from master), MISO (output to master), _CS (chip select from master), CLK (clock from master).

. Phase and Polarity fixed to mode 0.

. Support back-to-back transfer.

. Use MIO/EMIO routing interface of the zynq7000.

. 8-bits command/data.

. Basic command support: Read ID (0x1d), Read(0xea), Write(0xad). Limited to three commands for simplicity. Any other commands is rejected.

I have to write data from the microcontroller(data on ADC pin) and read to fpga. Please find the below mentioned microcontroller code.

```
// SPI interface pins
#define   MISO       PB3
#define   MOSI       PB2
#define   SCK        PB1
#define   CS         PB6 
#define   DDR_SPI    DDRB
#define   CS_low        PORTB&= ~(1<<(PB6))
#define   CS_high       PORTB|= (1<<(PB6))

#define spi_read_addr  0x00000020      // recieve register address from FPGA
#define spi_write_addr 0x0000001c      // Transmit register address from FPGA

 
ISR (ADC_vect)
{
    
    vol_buf= read_ADC();
    volt = (vol_buf*2.56)/1024;
    
    
    if(volt >= 0.9 && volt <= 0.9075)
    {
        PORTB = 0x01;
        PORTE = 0x30;
    }
    
    else if(volt >= 0.91 && volt <= 0.9175 )
    {
        
        PORTB =  0x01;
        PORTE = 0x40;
    }
 }

 

void init_ADC()
{
    ADMUX = 0x03;
    ADMUX |= ADMUX | 0xc0;                  // Internal 2.56V Voltage Reference & ADC3 is selected
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0);               // ADEN enable & ADIE=0
}

uint16_t read_ADC()
{
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
    while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));
    return ADC;
}

void init_SPImaster(void)
{
    DDR_SPI = (1<<MOSI) | (1<<SCK) | (1<<CS);  // set MOSI, SCK and CS as output and others as input
    SPCR = (1<<SPE) | (1<<MSTR) | (1<<SPR0);  // SPI enable , set as master and clock = fck/16
}

void SPI_masterWrite( unsigned char DataAddr , signed int count )
{
    if(volt>= 0.9 && volt <= 0.95)  
    {
        SPDR=DataAddr;
        while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))
        {
            //
        }
    }
    
}

void SPI_masterRead( unsigned char Addr , signed int count_ )
{
    if(volt>= 0.9 && volt <= 0.95)
    {
        SPDR=0;
        while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))
        {
            //
        }
    }
    
    Addr = SPDR;
    
}
```

Is the microcontroller code correct or not? How should I call read write function in main loop?

Comment: So what happened after you tested this out?

Comment: note that the same question was posted on AvrFreaks recently.